# Data retrieved from a NSMutableArray are different with the one I saved into it

Tags: objective-c, nsmutablearray

Why the value of  cells retrieved from a NSMutableArray is different with the ones I have originally stored in it?

I have a property of type NSMutableArray and I use it to hold an integer matrix with the following code

```
tiles = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:
         @1, @1, @1, @1, @1, @1,
         @1, @0, @0, @0, @0, @1,
         @1 ,@0, @0, @0, @0, @1,
         @1 ,@0, @0, @0, @0, @1,
         @1 ,@0, @0, @0, @0, @1,
         @1, @1, @1, @1, @1, @1,nil];


tileManager = [[TileManager alloc] init]; 
[tileManager CreateTilesMapRow:tilesMatrixWidth withColumns:tilesMatrixHeight byFlatDataArray:tiles];
```

and here is the retrieving part which always return @1 from NSMutableArray which is a "iso_wall"

```
-(void) placeAllTilesIso
{
    NSString *imageName;
    printf("Width , Height : %li , %li \n",(long)tilesMatrixWidth (long)tilesMatrixHeight);
    for (NSInteger i = 0;i<tilesMatrixWidth;i++)
   {
        for(NSInteger j = 0;j<tilesMatrixHeight;j++)
        {
            imageName = [tileManager getSpriteNameForRow:i andCol:j];
//HERE IS THE WRONG RESULT! Always says iso_wall! but It shouldn't if you take a look at tiles which includes both @0 and @1, where did the @0 went?
            NSLog(@"Sprite Got!  image name : %@ \n",imageName);
        }
    }
}
```

I have also defined a class and a header with names TileManager.m and TileManager.h that I plan to extend them in future, here is their codes :

### This is TileManager.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <math.h>
@interface TileManager : NSObject
@property (strong,nonatomic) NSMutableArray *tilesMatrix;
- (void) CreateTilesMapRow:(NSInteger) row withColumns:(NSInteger) col byFlatDataArray:(NSMutableArray*) flatArray;
- (NSString *) getSpriteNameForRow:(NSInteger) row andCol:(NSInteger) col;
@end
```

### This is TileManager.m

```
#import "tileManager.h"
@implementation TileManager

//NSMutableArray *tilesMatrix;

- (void) CreateTilesMapRow:(NSInteger) row withColumns:(NSInteger) col byFlatDataArray:(NSMutableArray *) flatArray
    {

    _tilesMatrix = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:row];
    NSMutableArray *innerTmp = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:col];
    for (int i = 0;i < col;i++) [innerTmp addObject:@0];
    for (int i = 0;i < row;i++) [_tilesMatrix addObject:innerTmp];

   for (NSInteger rowIndex=0; rowIndex < row;rowIndex++)   
     {
        for (NSInteger colIndex=0; colIndex < col; colIndex++)
        {
            _tilesMatrix[rowIndex][colIndex] =(NSString*) flatArray[rowIndex*col+colIndex];
        //READ ME
        // This show everything is ok and the _tileMatrix contains both 0 and 1
            NSLog(@"Create : row : %li    col : %li  val : %@",(long)rowIndex,(long)colIndex,_tilesMatrix[rowIndex][colIndex]);
            }
        }
    }
}
-(NSString *) getSpriteNameForRow:(NSInteger) row andCol:(NSInteger) col 
{
    //README
    // This always writes 1 which is incorrect
    NSLog(@"GET : row : %li    col : %li  val : %@",(long)row,(long)col,_tilesMatrix[row][col]);
    if ([_tilesMatrix[row][col] isEqual:@1])
        return (NSString *) @"iso_wall";
    else
        return (NSString *) @"iso_ground";
}
```

Why working with arrays is so hard in Objective C !!!

Comment: "Why working with arrays is so hard in Objective C" Well, you _could_ switch to Swift... :)

Comment: Still don't understand why is it so hard to work with arrays in Objective C, I never make such a mistake in c/c++ but Objective C !!!!! God give enough patient.

Comment: :) But in this case it had merely to do with the fact that you don't understand that object references are _pointers_. It has nothing to do with arrays at all.

Comment: @matt since I am a newbie in Objective C, do you think I should switch to swift?

Comment: Personally, yes. I have used and taught Objective-C for many years but I think Swift is a much better newbie language, with far cleaner syntax, and protecting the programmer from many kinds of mistake. (However, you _could_ have made a similar mistake to _this_ one in Swift, because class instance references are pointers in Swift as well.) - You can read my online book about Swift and decide whether this might be a better road to go down: http://www.apeth.com/swiftBook/

Comment: I don't understand how you managed to program in C/C++ without knowing what a pointer is.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion and Yes you are right it could happen in any pointer based language but why assigning a reference need a method! (add_object) come on! its only an address! I thought that will be passed by value, otherwise why a method!, by the way ......I will start swift tomorrow!

Comment: There's no reasonable way to add a value to a composite structure like an NSArray without doing a method call.  You couldn't do it in C or C++ either.  Of course, you're always welcome to use plain old C arrays in Objective-C, but most people avoid them since the benefits of using NSArray far outweigh any inconvenience 99% of the time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> for (int i = 0;i < col;i++) [innerTmp addObject:@0];
> ```

Fill `innerTmp` with `col` zeroes...

> ```
> for (int i = 0;i < row;i++) [_tilesMatrix addObject:innerTmp];
> ```

Add `innerTmp` `row` times to `_tilesMatrix`...

You've built a matrix where every row is a reference to the *same* object - `innerTmp`.

Maybe try:

```
[_tilesMatrix addObject:[innerTmp mutableCopy]];
```

so each row is distinct.

HTH

Comment: Thank you very much, Yes you were right, all rows were pointing at the first one which was a full row of  @1.

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible that these 2 line is causing the problem:

```
for (int i = 0;i < col;i++) [innerTmp addObject:@0];
for (int i = 0;i < row;i++) [_tilesMatrix addObject:innerTmp];
```

I can not run the code now unfortunately but everything else looked solid except these. Same `innerTmp` is being added to all rows. Same memory. Instead maybe:

```
for (int i = 0;i < row;i++) {
    NSMutableArray * innerTmp = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:col];
    for (int j = 0;j < col;j++) {
        [innerTmp addObject:@0];
    }
    [_tilesMatrix addObject:innerTmp];
}
```